# Json Decode in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

### I tried $json = json_decode($tracks1, true);

```
    Array ( [0] => [{"3430":"3430","1279":"1279","4925":"4925","3435":"3435","1899":"1899","1900":"1900","1901":"1901","1905":"1905","3971":"3971","4306":"4306","4962":"4962","4964":"4964"}] )
```

### Heading

> I want output like this

```
Array
(
    [3430] => 3430
    [1279] => 1279
    [4925] => 4925
    [3435] => 3435
    [1899] => 1899
    [1900] => 1900
    [1901] => 1901
    [1905] => 1905
    [3971] => 3971
    [4306] => 4306
    [4962] => 4962
    [4964] => 4964
)
```

I tried every thing . the error shown is

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

When i used  `$json = json_decode($tracks1, true);`

Comment: json_decode($tracks1[0], true);

Comment: This is because you have json inside json which is bad.

Comment: check  my update.

Comment: In the context of `$json = json_decode($tracks1, true);`, please, what's inside `$tracks1`?

Comment: i tried sir, but not worked

Comment: @romil what is the value/content of the `$tracks1`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => [{"3430":"3430","1279":"1279","4925":"4925","3435":"3435","1899":"1899","1900":"1900","1901":"1901","1905":"1905","3971":"3971","4306":"4306","4962":"4962","4964":"4964"}] )

Comment: @MdAbdulAwal shouldn't it be correct anyway?

Comment: @romil Also, could you post the original JSON? As a JSON, i mean, not as an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your input

```
Array ( [0] => [{"3430":"3430","1279":"1279","4925":"4925","3435":"3435","1899":"1899","1900":"1900","1901":"1901","1905":"1905","3971":"3971","4306":"4306","4962":"4962","4964":"4964"}] )
```

Try the below code. Because json is first element of your array

```
$json = json_decode($tracks1[0], true);
```

Comment: sir.... this solution got me answer but i have, more arrays like [1]=> [{.....}],[2]=> [{.....}],[3]=> [{.....}],      i couldnt write each for each index code. like $json = json_decode($tracks1[1], true);
 $json = json_decode($tracks1[2], true);   please give me solution

Comment: you can user foreach for the same. foreach($tracks1 as $track) {
   $json = json_decode($track, true);
   //further code here.
}

Comment: i tried but no result.

Comment: i want 3 array result, while 3 checkbox is checked.

Comment: it shown me only one array value, but i checked 3 checkbox.

Comment: You need to use those $json  data inside foreach. If you want to use those $json data outside foreach loop then you have to use array like:  $json = [];
foreach($tracks1 as $track) { $json[] = json_decode($track, true); //further code here. }
print_r($json);

Comment: great sir, it worked. sir, when i use $json on where clause it shown me "reg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array" this error."  "->where('id', $id)".

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked. Also pls share your complete code with where condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60181296/11469255

Comment: please check sir....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207629/discussion-between-sehdev-and-romil).

Comment: can you help me to solve this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606656/count-values-through-id-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Considering that

```
$json = '[{"3430":"3430","1279":"1279","4925":"4925","3435":"3435","1899":"1899","1900":"1900","1901":"1901","1905":"1905","3971":"3971","4306":"4306","4962":"4962","4964":"4964"}]';
$jsons = [$json, $json, $json];
$tracks = [];

foreach($jsons as $json) {
    $tracks = array_merge($tracks, json_decode($json, true));
}

var_dump($tracks);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6184b511505a26104201a56fec0e97e652a14361

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I updated the context according to the "requirements": I wrapped the json in an array.

Comment: sir.... this solution got me answer but i have, more arrays like [1]=> [{.....}],[2]=> [{.....}],[3]=> [{.....}], i couldnt write each for each index code. like $json = json_decode($tracks1[1], true); $json = json_decode($tracks1[2], true); please give me solution

Comment: @romil I updated the answer in order to be able to get all the elements

Comment: everytime i couldnt use $jsons = [$json, $json, $json];

Comment: I am a bit lost, sorry. That's not part of the original question... Maybe consider opening a new question with as many details as possible :)