# preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get `$id` value by JSON, when I use `$id` in `$tracks` `WHERE` clause it shown me this error

> preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

It shown like this:

```
Array
    $id = (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4843] => 4843
            [4844] => 4844


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [396] => 396

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [3963] => 3963

        )
    )
```

My controller:

```php
$track = Input::get('tracks');
$id = [];
foreach($track as $key => $tracks)
{
  $id[] = json_decode($tracks, true);
}

$tracks = Element::with(
    'composers', 
    'format_mp3s', 
    'loopsets.format_mp3s', 
    'mixes.format_mp3s', 
    'opening_key', 
    'closing_key', 
    'speed', 
    'mood', 
    'metre', 
    'tonic'
)
->where('id', $id)
->orderBy($sortBy, $dir)
->get();
```

Comment: sir when i used $id in where clause , it will shown me this error

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($track)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$ids` in `where` condition that is associative array that is why you are getting this error.

You can try below code to get only `ids` array and then pass them as `whereIn` condition to get the desired result

```
$newIds = [];
  foreach ($ids as $value) {
    foreach($value as $finalValue) {
      $newIds[] = $finalValue;
   }
}
```

Use `whereIn` instead of `where`

```
->whereIn('id', $newIds);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964095/convert-audio-to-a-tag-in-core-php can you please elp me to solve this.